# Access 2013 Append error

Tags: ms-access, append

I am doing Append query in Access 2013. 
It says to me that I am going to append 13 number (correct quantity) of rows; however, after I click Yes I get the error "...set 0 field(s) to Null due to a type conversion failure, and ....13 records due to key violations, and...due to validation rule violations." 
But when I created a temporary table and tried to append to that table first, and then that temporary table append to the destination table, it worked fine.
But when I did another copy of the Database, and applied all queries I used in the previous one, Append query didn't work again.
I did the research and I checked primary key, foreign keys, table settings, field settings,looked everywhere, it should work fine, but it doesn't..

The error message:
[image: Error append query]

The query:
[image: Append query]

```sql
INSERT INTO tblMain ( DispID, StartDate, ExpDate, AgreType, 
            VersionNo, OPSYEAR, CreatedBy, CreatedOn ) 
  SELECT TempTable_Update.DispID, TempTable_Update.StartDate,
    TempTable_Update.ExpDate, TempTable_Update.AgreType, 
    TempTable_Update.VersionNo, TempTable_Update.OPSYEAR, 
    TempTable_Update.CreatedBy, TempTable_Update.CreatedOn 
  FROM TempTable_Update
```

Please help me to solve this issues!

Comment: Please give some examples of the queries you are doing, and the exact errors. See: [How to ask.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And have you checked that the rows you are inserting really contain the correct value types (e.g. correct date/text/number format), and are you not using incorrect or double keys?

Comment: Yes, i have checked all rows I am inserting and they are correct. And I am not using primary key in append query and the primary key in a destination table is AutoNumber. I attached the screenshots in my original post.

Comment: Ok, could you add the SQL version of the query you do?
And this might be interesting: [How to fix Microsoft Office Access can't Append all the records in the append query.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/how-to-fix-microsoft-office-access-cant-append-all/34112ac4-db3d-4f05-9c17-ebfed549703b?auth=1)

Comment: INSERT INTO tblMain ( DispID, StartDate, ExpDate, AgreType, VersionNo, OPSYEAR, CreatedBy, CreatedOn )
SELECT TempTable_Update.DispID, TempTable_Update.StartDate, TempTable_Update.ExpDate, TempTable_Update.AgreType, TempTable_Update.VersionNo, TempTable_Update.OPSYEAR, TempTable_Update.CreatedBy, TempTable_Update.CreatedOn
FROM TempTable_Update;

Comment: The `TempTable_Update.DispID` is not in conflict with any `tblMain.DispID`?

Comment: Not, it is an index, it is just text field

Comment: can you post the design view of tblMain? do you have any relationships set that use tblMain?

Comment: Database was corrupted. It happened without any visible reason. So I remade the database, now it works fine. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database was corrupted. It happened without any visible reason. So I remade the database, now it works fine. Thank you all for your help!